# Какое предложение красноречивее?

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, какое предложение красноречивее: Напиши слово стол и стул или Напиши слова стол и стул?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Красноречивей первое, потому что корявое и заставляет обратить на себя внимание.

Красноречивей второе, потому что оно точное, правильное и не отвлекает слушателя от сути предложения.

Всё зависит от того, что мы хотим этой фразой добиться, чтобы её запомнили (первый вариант) или чтоб максимально быстро поняли (второй).

Answer (score 3):

По моему мнению, набор символов "Напиши слово стол и стул" следует квалифицировать как речеподражательный сигнал.

Comment: ответы ясны, спасибо всем!!!

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из определений (Красноречивый - 1. Отличающийся красноречием. 
2. Преисполненный красноречия 3. Без слов, но очень выразительно передающий чувства или настроения. // Убедительно свидетельствующий о чем-л.; Красноречие - умение говорить красиво и убедительно.), ярко выраженного красноречия в предложенных фразах не увидела:)